# Use of cache memory in iOS? What is the difference between cache memory and local storages like Core data (or) SQLite?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

By using core data and SQLite we can store the data locally in our device. What is the purpose of cache memory over there?

Comment: What do you mean by "catch memory"?

Comment: oh mistakenly!!. Its a 'cache'.. thanks.!

Comment: OK, now what do you mean by cache memory? Like the [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#MULTILEVEL)?